# will selecting and updating only a single column from a table improve performance

Tags: performance, entity-framework

i am trying to update only a single column in a table which has multiple columns.
Is it possible to select a single column value and update it using entity framework/linq.
will i get any performance advantage or improvement if i do so?
this is the code i have and i believe its retrieving only two columns and updating the column value against primary key.

```
int Uid = (int)Session["ID"];
        User u = new User();
        u.ID = Uid;
        u.phoneNu= "22144789";
        db.Users.Attach(u);
        db.Entry(u).Property(x => x.phoneNu).IsModified = true;
        db.SaveChanges();
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it will. This is a variation of the "Delete" trick which can be used.

The thing to watch out for is the lifetime scope of the DbContext you are using. For instance, if it is at all possible that prior to this call the DbContext instance could have loaded that entity then the `Attach` call can fail. This can creep into projects and slip through testing fairly easily.

For instance this is pretty much guaranteed to remain safe:

```
using (var db = new AppDbContext())
{ 
    var user = new User { ID = userId, PhoneNumber = newPhoneNumber };
    db.Users.Attach(user);
    db.Entry(user).Property(x => x.PhoneNumber).IsModified = true;
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

Because the scope of the DbContext is just this code via the `using` block. However, if your DbContext is injected, and there is the possibility that now or in the future that it *could* possibly have loaded that User within the scope of your request then `Attach` can throw if the context is already tracking that user. To guard against that:

```
User user = db.Users.Local.SingleOrDefault(x => x.ID == userId);
if (user == null)
{
   user = new User { ID = userId };
   db.Users.Attach(user);
}
user.PhoneNumber = phoneNumber;
db.SaveChanges();
```

This assumes `db` is injected. Hitting `Local` will just check the cache and doesn't hit the database. If one is already cached, we will use that, otherwise track a new instance. The added benefit of this approach is that you don't need to mark the column as modified as it is done automatically once the DbContext is tracking the entity after Attach. (Or already dealing with a tracked entity.)

The generated SQL in both cases will update just the one column by ID. You can verify this behaviour by using an SQL Trace:

```
exec sp_executesql N'UPDATE [dbo].[Users]
SET [PhoneNumber] = @0
WHERE ([ID] = @1)
',N'@0 nvarchar(max) ,@1 int',@0=N'22144789',@1=1
go
```

The last caveat of this approach is to dispose of the user and be sure that methods like this don't return the incomplete entity or pass it on to other methods. Doing so can lead to issues down the road as this newly created user will be missing all of the User details except the ID and phone number.